# roscore fails to start

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,
when i start roscore it complains about:

ImportError: No module named RosStreamHandler

in the file /opt/ros/fuerte/share/rosgraph/conf/python_logging.conf is

[handler_streamHandler]
class=rospy.impl.init.RosStreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=defaultFormatter
args=()

Where can i find the RosstreamHandler? how is this part in this file used ?

flo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60074/roscore-fails-to-start/) by [inflo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4215/inflo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 406 on 2013-04-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-06-13**:
How did you install ROS? What system are you running? This is not a common error, we need to be able to reproduce it to help you.  Please provide more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Duplicate? http://answers.ros.org/question/61454/any-solution-to-roscore-crash/

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0